# Create top and bottom borders smaller than the div itself

Tags: html, css, border

I have some text, and I would like to have a top and bottom border looking like a dash, kinda like this:

```
    -
texttext
    -
```

My code consists of a `div` with multiple `p` inside of it so I would like the short borders to be around the `div`. Is there a css way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes... Have you tried something ?

Comment: I usually try at least 2 or 3 solutions before asking on SO (as you can see in every question I asked in my profile) but this time I really had no idea where to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements:

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.text:before,
.text:after {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  content: '';
  width: 50px; /* change width to increase or decrease border */
  height: 1px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
}

.text:after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Some text here</div>
```